# How can I change the value of a cell depending on the value of another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell on my worksheet that holds the amount payable to debtors. I have another cell of amount paid. I need to know how I can be able to make the value of amount payable to decrease with the value of amount paid. So when the amount is completely paid, amount payable turns into 0.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Such scenarios are typically done with a row for each payment, where the payment is then subtracted from the balance.

[image]